# Data wont delete from table

Tags: c#, sql

I cannot get my program to clear an SQL database on opening. I have went through debugging and there are no errors in the code for deleting, but it just doesn't do it

```
string delete = "Delete from Trivia";
con.Open();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(delete, con);
con.Close();
```

Comment: You have to call `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` after you create the command.

Comment: wow... duh. sorry still new to putting SQL in my program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually executing the command. You might also consider a `using` statement. That will automatically dispose of the connection properly, even if an error occurs:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("delete from Trivia", con);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```